# Rack Pick in a custom flowchart with a dynamic event and dates from a database

Tags: anylogic

I would like to release the number of pallets (n) to the picktime of my dbase. I use my custom flowchart Store_and_Pick for different process flows. So I get the error The method create_MyDynamicEvent(long, TimeUnits, int) is undefined for the type Main but dynamic event and the loop trough the dbase are both in Main. The wait block is in the custom flowchart. So don't know where my mistake is. I know that the error says is is the wrong location but why?

[image: dbase]

[image: customflow]

[image: DE]

[image: main_DE]

[image: Main_loop]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the help on DEs. When you name a DE something (for example "myDE"), AnyLogic creates a method that pre-ceedes the name with "create_". In this example, "create_myDE()".

You named your DE `create_MyDynamicEvent` already, so there is no method `create_MyDynamicEvent(...)`. Instead, there will be a method `create_create_MyDynamicEvent(...)` :)

So give you DE a normal name without `create_` .

NOTE: Please use code-completion when you type code and you would have noticed this. Ctrl+space on Windows. See here: https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fui%2FUsing+Intelli-sense.html&resultof=%22%63%6f%64%65%22%20%22%63%6f%6d%70%6c%65%74%65%22%20%22%63%6f%6d%70%6c%65%74%22%20
Never write code without it!